# How to add emission to Unity custom shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I use the following shader in Unity.
Ring like sonar is spreading from the place where game objects collided.
With reference to the underlying image.
[image: Image of sonar effect.]
I would like to add emission to make this ring visible even in the dark, but I am new to shaders. I am in trouble because I do not know where to change.

The setting for making it dark is as follows.

1. Set the Intensity Multiplier of Environment Lightning to 0.
2. Remove skybox.
3. Set the Background of Camera to black.

The shader I use is below.

```c#
Shader "MadeByProfessorOakie/SimpleSonarShader" {
    Properties{
        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _RingColor("Ring Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _RingColorIntensity("Ring Color Intensity", float) = 2
        _RingSpeed("Ring Speed", float) = 1
        _RingWidth("Ring Width", float) = 0.1
        _RingIntensityScale("Ring Range", float) = 1
        _RingTex("Ring Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader{
        Tags{ "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _RingTex;


        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float3 worldPos;
            float3 uv_Illum;
        };

        // The size of these arrays is the number of rings that can be rendered at once.
        // If you want to change this, you must also change QueueSize in SimpleSonarShader_Parent.cs
        half4 _hitPts[20];
        half _StartTime;
        half _Intensity[20];

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;
        fixed4 _RingColor;
        // 追加
        fixed4 _EmissionLM;
        half _RingColorIntensity;
        half _RingSpeed;
        half _RingWidth;
        half _RingIntensityScale;


        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;

            half DiffFromRingCol = abs(o.Albedo.r - _RingColor.r) + abs(o.Albedo.b - _RingColor.b) + abs(o.Albedo.g - _RingColor.g);


            // Check every point in the array
            // The goal is to set RGB to highest possible values based on current sonar rings
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

                half d = distance(_hitPts[i], IN.worldPos);
                half intensity = _Intensity[i] * _RingIntensityScale;
                half val = (1 - (d / intensity));

                if (d < (_Time.y - _hitPts[i].w) * _RingSpeed && d >(_Time.y - _hitPts[i].w) * _RingSpeed - _RingWidth && val > 0) {
                    half posInRing = (d - ((_Time.y - _hitPts[i].w) * _RingSpeed - _RingWidth)) / _RingWidth;

                    // Calculate predicted RGB values sampling the texture radially
                    float angle = acos(dot(normalize(IN.worldPos - _hitPts[i]), float3(1,0,0)));
                    val *= tex2D(_RingTex, half2(1 - posInRing, angle));
                    half3 tmp = _RingColor * val + c * (1 - val);

                    // Determine if predicted values will be closer to the Ring color
                    half tempDiffFromRingCol = abs(tmp.r - _RingColor.r) + abs(tmp.b - _RingColor.b) + abs(tmp.g - _RingColor.g);
                    if (tempDiffFromRingCol < DiffFromRingCol)
                    {
                        // Update values using our predicted ones.
                        DiffFromRingCol = tempDiffFromRingCol;
                        o.Albedo.r = tmp.r;
                        o.Albedo.g = tmp.g;
                        o.Albedo.b = tmp.b;
                        o.Albedo.rgb *= _RingColorIntensity;
                    }
                }
            }

            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
        }

        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always worth to have a look at the Built-In shaders when you create custom shaders.
Just pick those which behave the way you want and see what they do.

Here is an example for the BlinnPhong surface:

```
//Properties
_EmissionLM ("Emission (Lightmapper)", Float) = 0
[Toggle] _DynamicEmissionLM ("Dynamic Emission (Lightmapper)", Int) = 0

//Output
o.Emission = c.rgb * tex2D(_Illum, IN.uv_Illum).a;
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
But it did not work.
I am attaching this shader to the wall and the floor, but as I write it according to the answer, the walls and the floor itself glowed.
I want to shine the ring that comes out when objects collide with each other, not the wall and the floor itself.

Comment: @MIIKA did you copy and paste this verbatim, or simply pull what you needed from it? Your self-answer demonstrates that you simply added a line to set the `Emission` property in your shader. Thus, this answer technically answers your question.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved. I rewrote the code as follows. Thank you very much for those who thought.
I rewrote as follow.

```
 // Determine if predicted values will be closer to the Ring color
            half tempDiffFromRingCol = abs(tmp.r - _RingColor.r) + abs(tmp.b - _RingColor.b) + abs(tmp.g - _RingColor.g);
            if (tempDiffFromRingCol < DiffFromRingCol)
            {
                // Update values using our predicted ones.
                //DiffFromRingCol = tempDiffFromRingCol;
                /*
                o.Albedo.r = tmp.r;
                o.Albedo.g = tmp.g;
                o.Albedo.b = tmp.b;
                o.Albedo.rgb *= _RingColorIntensity;
                */
                // I Changed here
                o.Emission = tmp;

            }
```

Comment: [@NoobProgrammer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48744301/9893154) proposes that you set the emission property in your shader as your answer demonstrates that you did.